# Gradle 5.1.1 update breaks my proguard rules in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, proguard, android-r8

I updated my gradle version to 5.1.1 and suddenly it broke some of my proguard rules (app crashes). An example would be this library that I use:
https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview

I applied the proguard rule:

```
-keeppackagenames org.jsoup.nodes
```

Which was working before (v4.10.1 and below) but now it broke and it gives this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not read resource entities-xhtml.properties. Make sure you copy resources for cMb
```

My question is, did you add any special rules when you are updating your version to 5.1.1? I know that starting from this version of Android Studio (3.4) it comes with R8 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was resolved by adding

> -keep class org.jsoup.**

Answer (score 0):

Adding as an answer entry, since I can't yet comment :-(

We would need more information to narrow down if this is an issue in R8 or case of missing keep rules. If you [file a bug report on R8](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=326788&template=1025938), including information that could help us investigate, such as your APK if possible, we will do our best to help you out!